# Android Surface View update

Tags: android, multithreading, animation, surfaceview

I have multiple animations on a single activity and each animation is its own surface view and thread. Some of these images are animated around a fixed image, it seems that in the thread of the surface draw function it keeps calling the onDraw() function for as long as the thread is running,  this repaints the static image as well as the animation....making it very slow. Is there a way i can get it to only refresh or repaint the animated object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but you want to use static types and do not instantiate them, this speeds up things a little. And also I don't think you should have those threads on the separate images... You should render a complete screen on a separate thread. This is mobile developmnet, they have hardware limitations, kepp that in mind! =]